# Duplicate chooser is unreadable in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, vote-to-close, dark-mode

First row result shows the undesirable result; second row shows a highlighted item, showing the stats data;

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally deployed a fix to this one! Hopefully the fix is an improvement. Thanks for filing!